# Get all strings between two patterns in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

On my node.js server, I have a string, which contains html (unescaped) and a few (not only one, but more) img tags with base64 src and I need to get all base64 strings in an array from it and than decode those base64's into images, save them somewhere on the server and replace base64 strings with img address, for example I need to change this

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw...some-pretty-damn-long-string...K5CYII=" style="foo:bar;" possible-other-attribude="baz"/>
```

to this:

```
<img src="/media/images/filename.png" style="foo:bar;" possible-other-attribude="baz"/>
```

I have no problem with the actual decoding, saving to .png and than replacing in the string, but I don't know how to get the Array with all base64 strings. Thanks for help.

Comment: What about `str.match(/data:image/png;base64,[A-Za-z0-9+\/]+/g)`?

Comment: What does [that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) return if not an array (or `null` in case nothing was found)? Maybe you have forgotten the `g`lobal modifier…

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the best solution. I really should learn regex...

Comment: @Bergi My bad, it really is an array (that's why I removed the comment as soon as I found it out). I was confused, because when I console.logged the result, id didn't show [] brackets as other arrays do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var strings = htmlCode.match(/src="data:[a-z\/]+;base64,.+?"/g)

for(var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++)
{
    doSomething(strings[i].match(/,(.+?)"/)[1]);
}
```